# Return by reference to change CodeIgniter database configs

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying change the database config at execution time in CI. I've had a little progress,but here we use 3 database managers: ActiveRecord(native from CI),Lumine(a small and old ORM) and Doctrine. I'll try explain better.

In CI exists a database static config file,called [database.php](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html). In that file you put the configs,in a matrix format:

```
$db['config_group']['username']
$db['config_group']['password']
```

Well,I had to create a Class to generate and return that configuration. So I found a way that I could change it dinamically:

[DatabaseClass](http://pastebin.com/mT97eqb0)

Then in the database.php I call it:

```
$database = DatabaseManager::initDatabase('address',"user","db");
$active_record = &$database->getActiveRecord();
$active_group  = &$database->getActiveGroup();
$db = &$database->exportConfigCI();
```

[Full database.php file](http://pastebin.com/C1zyPB2S)

Fine! It makes and exports the config for me. Note that I call it with return by reference. Now, it's the time to **change it**. I have to make a change in the user of DB, according to the type of user logged. So I build a hook of type *post_controller_constructor*.

[Hook to change DB config](http://pastebin.com/2HqDxfdF)

The problem: The reference is lost in the middle of the process. No matter how I try, I can't change the values of **CI->db** object(the object that holds the database attributes). By polymorphism(how I show in the hook) I can do that, but only to ActiveRecord. The others ORM's are based on database.php file. Here I need of return by reference, to change all dependencies linked at database config file.

Doctrine and Lumine config files are linked to the same *database.php* from CI.

[Lumine config file](http://pastebin.com/rfjSykCi)

[Doctrine config file](http://pastebin.com/vuaHkvEv)

What am I missing? It's possible do what I want?

Comment: Is your goal to handle multiple databases?

Comment: @Linesofcode,nope.
It's a legacy application,so there are a high cost of maintenance. Through the time,there are migrations of libraries,so today we have three databases managers. What I'm trying to do is build a way of change the database user to limit the actions of users,according the user type . If I verify the type at any insert in the system,will be a infinite job. So,change the user db by a user without permissions and catch the exceptions is a more clever way,I think.

Ps: I edit the question with **Doctrine** , **Lumine** and the full **database.php** config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and now I had enough time to elaborate an answer. As I said,I needed change the DB core config for multiple db managers linked to CI database config file (**Doctrine**,**Lumine** and **CI active record** itself). The main problem was that once loaded,the CI database object holds its state immutable. Said that,if you need change the db user or other attribute at execution time,it will not work by just calling the $CI->db object and changing it.

**The solution:**

Create a class to manage and export all the configs from db,access the  attributes and methods and return by reference.

**How it works,in simple steps?**

The database config file has became a class. That class,as I said,manages and exports the db attributes returning by reference,in the array format from CI.

[DatabaseClass](http://pastebin.com/JSYETnwQ)

In the ORM's configuration files linked to CI db file,a call by reference is made as well.

```
$user = &$database->getUsername();
$pass = &$database->getPassword();
```

[DoctrineConfigFile](http://pastebin.com/ztzrEgF1)

*The same happens to the **Lumine** file.*

**Changing the configs at execution time**

To change the db user at execution time,a *post_controller_construct* hook has been created. The hook checks the user mode(*superuser:* can view the system as other user - or a normal user) at every request. If the user is a superuser,him can view and use the system as other user,but cannot realize some operations,like inserts and deletes. The hook then make the changes,getting the attributes values from the Database class,and switching the user db by a user without permissions to perform such actions.

Something like this:

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $database = DatabaseManager::initDatabase();
    $user = &$database->getUsername();
    $active_group = &$database->getActiveGroup();
    $active_group = "vision_group";
    $user = "vision_user";
```

Then,change the values linked too:

```
    $referencePass = "my-encrypted-and-encapsulated-pass-for-user-vision";

    //lumine management
    $LumConnManager = Lumine_ConnectionManager::getInstance();
    $LumConfList = $LumConnManager->getConfigurationList();
    $lumineConfig = current($LumConfList);

    $lumineConfig->connection->setPassword($referencePass);
    $lumineConfig->connection->setUser($user);
```

And finally,overriding the original DB Object from CI:

```
   $dbObject = DB($active_group);
   $CI->db = $dbObject;
```

[ChangeDatabaseHook](http://pastebin.com/UqEyvk87)

As Doctrine doesn't have a deep chain for this configuration,his values are changed just by the reference.

It's important note that the **active_group** parameter defines the configuration group. By this reason,we have to deal with two  groups. The default group and the 'limited group',and then override the default object with a object that holds the new active group - the group with restrictions to perform actions on database.

We just need to change the *user*,*pass* and *group* params. Others configurations still the same.

The PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) provides more information about returning references.

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

Comment: I can't do that way. There are so many calls in the system that I have to override the 'normal' db object. When the system change the db user,the user logged get a message of unauthorized operation,if is a  insert action,by example.